# Excel VBA to copy and manipulate values and leave the results lower on the same sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my question:

Every day i get sent an excel sheet with a variable number of rows. Some days it is 100 rows, other days it is 50, but always, the columns contain the same sorts of data in 12 columns.

I paste the results (after 2 empty rows) down below the original data, and I then process the columns in the sheet to modify some of the data before and sending it on.

Here is an example sheet with 3 rows of 4 columns each:

1001   100    1    100
1002   100    2    200
1003   101    1    300

I need to come up with a result where the items in the first column are incremented by 500, and the items in the second column are incremented by 50, items in the third column are simply copied, and items in the fourth are incremented by 10....and so on for the 12 columns. The results are them pasted in after 2 empty rows...So the final result would look like this:

1001   100    1    100
1002   100    2    200
1003   101    1    300
(empty row1)
(empty row2)
1501   150    1    110
1502   150    2    210
1503   151    1    310

As you can see...some columns are pasted down below the original data "as is", and other columns are changed based on the original value with a calculation applied. The thing is i don't know how many rows the original list contains each day, and my attempts at using a formula to fix this up keep failing due to the unknown number of source rows.

I know if i use a Visual Basic loop I can insert formulas into the cells to make the sheet behave as i want, but i don't know where to start. Anyone ever see anything like this before? I don't want to use excel formulas because my sheet sizes are variable and sometimes require a little logic to sort out. (I can't just copy and paste excel formulas into each row, I need logic in the function to work out what is going on that day)

Thanks all, you are a fantastic community here!

Jamie

Comment: have u tried anything to code . ?

Comment: I tried to get vb to copy formulas into new cells with code in them to make the new answers (i.e. for row 6, above it might be =sum(a1+500) however i could not figure out how to get that to only run for each row that exists, and not paste below forever downwards!  Thanks for looking - Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are new to VBA. Below code satisfies your 1st condition ( first column are incremented by 500)

```
Sub test()
Dim erange As Range
Dim lrow As Integer

With ActiveSheet
lrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each erange In .Range("A1:A" & lrow)

erange.Offset(lrow + 2, 0).Value = erange.Value + 500

Next erange


End With



End Sub
```

you should try to code rest ..let me know if u find any difficulty

**Section 2**

***If you want to replace particular string with other string then u could use replace function.. Below is the example***

```
erange.Offset(lrow + 2, 0).Value = Replace(erange.Value, "_incomplete", "_processing")
```

Comment: Thanks! I am brand new to VB and just trying to work it out. Thank you very kindly for your time. I am also working with a loop "With Active sheet" and I will try to paste what I did here also. Jamie

Comment: I see it works! Wow!! I am trying to now add modifications to Col B in the same loop as when I call another function "test2" Haha. I will keep at it.

Comment: Pls vote up .. if it really helped..Let me know if u need any help :)\

Comment: I got it to work perfectly, but I have one question, in one column I have to remove the text "_incomplete" from the items in the source and substitute "_processing" instead. (but only if "_processing" is at the end of the value...This falls at the end of the text string in each case. I also have three columns (G,H, J) which are always just copied downwards, so I am working on a loop which will simply copy those three at once!

Comment: trying to upvote you but i still need reputation. Will do so as i get it!

Comment: No Probs .. Plz see section 2 in my ans .

Comment: Thanks. I have made 5 small subs which each do the work on one column - then i can call them from a master function. This is going to save me so much time! I will try your replace code in the morning!

Comment: I noticed one problem with my approach - One of the columns i am working with contains "descriptions", which are not always added (they may be blank). The problem is that using this method, the column of items pastes 2 below the final entry (in that column) which may not be the right position. (as opposed to 2 below the final row of information in the rest of the columns). This results in a situation where the copy of the "description" column doesn't line up with the other columns on the list. I'm trying to sort out a solution now.

Comment: You could raise another question for this with more clarity explanation .. I ll help you :).